# Twisted equivariant K-theory: Inverse construction possible?

Tags: rt.representation-theory

This is a complete reformulation of a post I closed (I'm no profi, evidently I didn't do enough math research).

A Verlinde algebra $V$ is commutative, associative and unital, with the "fusion rules" usually written as (with $A_n\in V$) $A_i\bigotimes A_j=N_{ij}^k\cdot A_k$ with $N_{ij}^k\in\mathbb{N}_0$. (If necessary, consider only "faithful" (slight name abuse, but same concept) $V$ where $\exists A_m\in V | \forall_i A_i\in A_m^{\bigotimes n}$.)

[As stated in the wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Verlinde_algebra&section=2#Twisted_equivariant_K-theory), from the irreps of any compact Lie algebra $G$ you can generate some $V$, and possibly more than one.

Is the converse true? Can you find, for any given $V$, some compact Lie algebra $G$ such that the construction given in [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Verlinde_algebra&section=2#Twisted_equivariant_K-theory), applied to $G$, reproduces $V$? (This is especially my question for "exceptional" $V$ like that connected to the Haagerup subfactor.)

Also note "irrep isomorphism": $E7_{1/2}$ is not semisimple, but the structure of $44^{\bigotimes n}$ is isomorphous to (e.g.) $E7,56^{\bigotimes n}$ by sextonion magic. (Still the set of generatable $V$ might differ, since the allowed roots of unity $q$ might? I didn't check that.) Thus it is also natural to ask if a "yes" to the former question means "yes, and even a semisimple $G$ always exists".